# How to save JavaScript code in localStorage and execute it later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm wondering if it's even possible to save some js code and pull it up later and execute.

There are basically two problems I'm facing:

- How to stringify the javascript code?
- How to execute the stringified javascript code?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to retrieve the text blob and dynamically drop it inside a `<script>` tag.

This works in the Chrome and MSIE 9 consoles - I didn't try Firefox yet:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.appendChild(document.createTextNode('alert("hello")'));
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

As for stringifying the code, it's normally possible to call `myFunction.toString()` on user supplied functions.

Comment: @Imp because `eval` is evil and can almost always be avoided.

Comment: We are targeting QT webkit, so if it works on chrome, it should work for us for the most part too. Do you think it's possible to use `.toString()` on the whole Javascript MVC class? Or would you suggest to wrap them into a function and use `myFn.toString()` ?

Comment: @shershams dunno - suggest you just try it! ;-)  Note that anything wrapped up in an _immediately invoked function expression_ won't work - you need some sort of handle to the function.

Comment: @Alnitak But why is `eval` evil? Because someone said so? No, it is because opens space for malicious code. But in this case, you are downloading your own code and it absolutely no difference if you put it in `eval` or `<script>`. Besides, `eval` is well implemented in all browsers - on the other hand, dynamically adding scripts with `<script>` tag works a little different on different browser (done wrong way, the code wouldn't execute).

Comment: IE treats `<script>` and `<style>` tags in a special way, as they don't represent visible elements of the page. It is impossible to append a text node as a child to these elements in IE.

Comment: @Imp interesting - does that apply to all versions?

Comment: @Alnitak I don't know about the newest (9, 10). But it wasn't possible on the previous ones.

Comment: @Alnitak Cool. At least they are really stepping towards standardization :)

Comment: @Alnitak So I created a sample, but can't get it to work. Just running this on js console: `var test = function(){ alert("test"); }` -> `test.toString();` returns `"function(){ alert("test"); }"` -> use `eval( 'function(){ alert("test"); }' );` -> `SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`. I know `eval('alert("test")');` will work, but what about the whole function?

Comment: And what if the function accepts parameters? How can you call that function using `eval()`?

Comment: @shershams if the string is a function body you need to assign the _result_ of `eval` to another variable which you can then invoke.  See http://jsfiddle.net/puANH/1/

Comment: @Alnitak - http://jsfiddle.net/puANH/3/ - fixed a minor bug, but it's still throwing the same error. It cannot evaluate the function.

Comment: @Imp 's comments about "Because someone said so?" are maybe the most important thing in this thread. eval isn't evil if you understand what it is. Just think about what you're doing before doing it.